# Приведение типов двумерного массива

Tags: c#

Есть массив

> float[,] arr1;

Как его преобразовать в `double[,]`?

Comment: Convert.ToDouble(arr1);?

Answer (score 4):

Если под «преобразовать» вы понимаете «создать новый массив», то так:

```
double[,] Convert(float[,] arr)
{
    int d0 = arr.GetLength(0), d1 = arr.GetLength(1);
    var result = new double[d0, d1];
    for (int i0 = 0; i0 < d0; i0++)
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < d1; i1++)
            result[i0, i1] = arr[i0, i1];
    return result;
}
```

Если речь идёт о преобразовании типов «на месте», то, боюсь, никак.

Comment: А какой нибудь `reinterpret_cast` с магией `__makeref` не может разве сделать преобразовании типов «на месте»?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan: Не смогут. Хотя бы потому, что размер данных в памяти разный.